# Xamarin circular activity indicator for UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, activity-indicator

Is there a custom circular activity indicator for UWP/ Win10 apps using Xamarin?

Comment: Have you tried checking out ProgressRing?

Comment: @AbsoluteSith there's no ProgressRing in Xamarin :/

Comment: Yeah you have write a custom renderer for that I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a custom circular activity indicator for UWP/ Win10 apps using Xamarin?

You need to create your own `View` for UWP's [ProgressRing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressring.aspx):

**Shared Project\MyProgressRing.cs:**

```cs
public class MyProgressRing:View
{
}
```

**UWP Project\MyProgressRingRenderer.cs:**

```cs
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyProgressRing),typeof(MyProgressRingRenderer))]
namespace CircularActivityDemo.UWP
{
    public class MyProgressRingRenderer:ViewRenderer<MyProgressRing,ProgressRing>
    {
        ProgressRing ring;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyProgressRing> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                ring = new ProgressRing();
                ring.IsActive = true;
                ring.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                ring.IsEnabled = true;
                SetNativeControl(ring);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes: I hardcoded the properties of `ProgressRing` Control. You can create DependencyProperties for your custom `ProgressRing` control.